# Recommendation: Deploy Docker application to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I got a local Docker stack running Node.js, MongoDB and Nginx.
It runs perfectly using `docker-compose up --build`.

Now it's time to deploy my application to a production environment.

I have considered EC2 Container Service and EC2, but can you recommend an easier approach? The learning curve is steep!

Answer (score 1):

- **For MongoDB -**

  Use AWS quick start MongoDB
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/overview.html
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/architecture.html
- **For rest of the docker stack i.e NodeJS & Nginx -**

  Use the AWS ElasticBeanstalk Multi Container Deployment
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk supports Docker, as [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html). Elastic Beanstalk would manage the EC2 resources for you so that you, which should make things a bit easier on you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Kontena](https://www.kontena.io) to [AWS](https://kontena.io/docs/getting-started/installing/aws-ec2.html) and use that to deploy your application to production environment (of course other cloud providers are also supported). Transition from Docker Compose is very smooth since [kontena.yml](http://kontena.io/docs/references/kontena-yml.html) uses similar syntax and keys as docker-compose.yml.

With Kontena you will have private image registry, load balancer and secret management built-in that are very useful when running containers in production.